# NullPointerException after installing cassandra on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cassandra, ubuntu-18.04, java-11

After the classic installation of cassandra on a development machine, I launched the `nodetool` and I got following output:

```sh
error: null
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.DatabaseDescriptor.getDiskFailurePolicy(DatabaseDescriptor.java:1892)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.JVMStabilityInspector.inspectThrowable(JVMStabilityInspector.java:82)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.FileUtils.<clinit>(FileUtils.java:79)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.FBUtilities.getToolsOutputDirectory(FBUtilities.java:860)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.printHistory(NodeTool.java:200)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.NodeTool.main(NodeTool.java:168)
```

I looked for a similar problem, but Cassandra's support of Java 11 is really new and I can not install Java 8, which is the only solution, to solve the problem.

Ubuntu version

```sh
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Java version

```sh
java 11.0.2 2019-01-15 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.2+9-LTS, mixed mode)
```

Cassandra status

```sh
● cassandra.service - LSB: distributed storage system for structured data
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cassandra; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-05-08 12:30:58 CEST; 15min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2350 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cassandra start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Thank you in advance for your solutions and advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All existing releases of Cassandra work only with Java 8, and can't work with Java 9,10,11,... Corresponding changes are in Cassandra 4.0, but it's not clear when then release will be available.

You need to install Java 8 to run Cassandra.

Comment: Need to update jdk and alternatives.
https://www.geofis.org/en/install/install-on-linux/install-openjdk-8-on-ubuntu-trusty/